# MySQl Query Required

Tags: mysql, join

I have one table

```
ID    Details   User_id Last_ID
2960    ABC     52294
10532   PQR     61629   61629
11050   XYZ     69
```

and other

```
Id    UserName
69      aaaa
52294   bbbb
61629   cccc
```

**Please provide a query to get following data**

```
ID    Details   UserName last_id
```

Comment: Perform JOIN over your tables

Comment: What query have you tried?  what does the result look like?

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.details, b.UserName, a.Last_ID
FROM one_table as a,
INNER JOIN other_table as b ON b.id = a.user_id
```

see [mysql join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Details, u.UserName 
FROM details d, usernames u 
WHERE d.User_id = u.Id
```

Comment: Please avoid posting answers with implicit join syntax, always teach users to use the proper syntax of joins!

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.id ,t1.details,t2.userName 
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.user_id =t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    a.id,a.details,b.username
from
    first_table a,second_table b
where 
    a.userid = b.id
```

Comment: I have made certain changes to my question... Could you please check